# Mirror function with respect to a straight line

Tags: inverse-function

I have a question for which I have unfortunately not come up with an answer so far. If I want to mirror a function on the bisector, then $f(x)=y$ applies and then I have the inverse. So far so good. But what do I do now if I want to mirror a function on a straight line with a 40 degree angle, for example?
I have these two exemplary functions:

1. $$f(x)=0.2*e^{0.5x}$$
2. $$f(x)=0.8x$$

How do I mirror function 1 on function 2? I tried it with $y=0.8x$ and then applied the same procedure as above, but it didn't work. How does it work then? Thanks in advance

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

By intersecting a line $r$ with a line $s$ passing through $(x,y)$ and perpendicular to $r$, we have:

$$
(x_0,y_0) + (a,b)\,u = (x,y) + (-b,a)\,v
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
\begin{cases}
u = \frac{a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)}{a^2+b^2} \\
v = \frac{b(x-x_0)-a(y-y_0)}{a^2+b^2} \\
\end{cases}\,.
$$

Therefore, the point $(x',y')$ symmetrical of $(x,y)$ with respect to $r$ is:

$$
\boxed{(x',y') = (x,y) + (-b,a)\left(2\frac{b(x-x_0)-a(y-y_0)}{a^2+b^2}\right)}\,.
$$

---

In your case, since $\color{magenta}{r}$ passes through $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ and has director vector $(a,b)=(5,4)$:

$$
(x',y') = \left(\frac{9x+40y}{41},\frac{40x-9y}{41}\right)
$$

from which it follows that the points of the curve $\color{blue}{(x,y) = (t,e^{t/2}/5)}$ will be symmetrized in:

$$
\color{red}{(x,y) = \left(\frac{9t+8e^{t/2}}{41},\frac{200t-9e^{t/2}}{205}\right)}
$$

where as $t$ varies in $\mathbb{R}$ we obtain the points of the blue and red curves of our interest.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

---

On the other hand, if for some reason a Cartesian equation is preferred:

$$
\color{blue}{y = \frac{1}{5}e^{\frac{x}{2}}}
\quad \quad \Rightarrow \quad \quad
\color{red}{\frac{40x-9y}{41} = \frac{1}{5}e^{\frac{9x+40y}{82}}}
$$

where to make $\color{red}{y}$ explicit it's necessary to use the *Lambert W function*:

$$
\color{red}{y = \frac{40}{9}x - \frac{41}{20}\,\mathcal{W}\left(\frac{4}{9}e^{\frac{41}{18}x}\right)}.
$$

This proves that it isn't always possible to get the *symmetric function* in an elementary way.